# How can I make one database call instead of two when rendering an image from a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a model (with an underlying PostGres database) with some basic data columns

```
 name         | character varying           |
 image        | bytea                       | not null
 content_type | character varying           | not null
```

"image" is the binary data of the image that I'd like to display.  I would like to create a page to display both the image and the name but I can't figure out how to do this without multiple database calls.  My show view looks like

```
<h1>Votes#show</h1>
<h2><%= @person.name %></h2>
<img src="<%= url_for(:controller => "people",
                      :action => "image",
                      :id => @person.id) %>" />
```

As you can see, to render the image, I have to call a separate controller method .  The method that displays this show page is

```
  def show
    id = params[:id]
    ...
        @person = Person.find_by_id(id)
  end
```

and teh controller method that sends the image data is

```
  def image
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    send_data(@person.image,
                :filename => @person.name,
                :type => @person.content_type,
                :disposition => "inline")
  end
```

Does anyone know how I can simplify my view so that I only need to invoke one database call to get my data instead of two?

Comment: Add the rails console log of the two queries being made

Comment: One is "SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]" and the othe ris "SELECT  "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]".  Have I not provided enough code to prove that two calls are hapepning?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do this?:

```
<h1>Votes#show</h1>
<h2><%= @person.name %></h2>
<%= image_tag @person.image %>
```

Comment: That results in an error, "string contains null byte".  "@people.image" contains binary data, btw

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the id back, why not send the object (you already found it)? A bit new to ruby, so not sure if this is technically correct, but it seems like you could do:

```
<img src="<%= url_for(:controller => "people",
                      :action => "image",
                      :id => @person) %>" />
```

And in the controller just use the @person object instead of looking it up again. Might want to re-name id to person or something, too.

Comment: But if my "@person" object contains the binary data of an image (potentially 500kb), in your call where you send the object back, aren't I uploading all data back to the server?  That seems a little bandwidth intensive, no?

Comment: Mmmm true. You could store it in cache, temporarily. Something like: Rails.cache.write('cache-key', person) and Rails.cache.read('cache-key'). You can delete it when you're done: Rails.cache.delete('cache-key'). By default, memory_store can hold up to 32 Mb I think.

Comment: You mean store it in cache instead of the rendering method you suggest?  If so what would teh code be for the rendering of the image?

Comment: Either go back to your original @person.id (in the url_for), or better yet, don't pass anything at all. In your show method, after you find the person, store it in the cache (Rails.cache.write('cache-key', @person)). Then in your image method, read the person from the cache instead of db (@person = Rails.cache.read('cache-key')).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  This seems like a little bit of a hack and I fear it would not work in an environment with more than one server unless those caches get somehow linked.  Also I 'm concerned about the cache size under load.  But a good out of the box idea.